# Would God Speak saying "Our" instead of "I"

Tags: spirit, elohim, holy

Would the Lord speak to His children in prayer and say things in plural form? since He is Father, Son, and Holy Spirit?

I was in prayer at the altar at church and it's been a couple of times already that I hear what may be the Holy Spirit say, "You are our daughter".  It has me in quite the conundrum.

I know there is scripture referring to God as "us" like when referring to Genesis where we can "know the knowledge of good and evil like 'us'" or when God said "let 'us' make man in 'our' image"

so would it be plausible that God would speak in our form as well?

I say 'may be' the Holy Spirit because I am sensitive to God's Spirit, I can feel and hear Him, but I am also sensitive to other spirits, spirits that are unclean.  I'm learning how to discern the two.  It says in the Bible that the enemy uses the Word of God against us.  He twists it, turns it into half truths.  the temptation of Jesus is a perfect example, and the temptation of Eve as well.

I just want to learn if He would say this to me.  My Lord and Saviour. thank you for your time. God Bless.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. As it stands, your question could possibly be closed for focusing on a particular scripture for analysis. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: I think you have answered your own question.

Comment: It is debatable whether "us" and "we" in Gen 1 & 2 is referring to the Trinity - it could be referring to God and the other heavenly being such as those listed in Job 38:1-7.  We are not told.  In any case, there are only four times that plural pronouns are used by God in the OT - Gen 1:26, 3:22, 11:7, Isa 6:8.

Comment: @agarza  When you commented, "possibly be closed for focusing on a particular scripture for analysis", did you mean to say "for NOT focusing..."? (as the Q does not mention any text)

Comment: @Anne Yes, my apologies. Sometimes my fingers don't keep up with my thoughts.